# Verbs in these sentences

Tags: verbs, functions

In the sentence
“I went jogging” am I correct in thinking “went” is the verb? And jogging a gerund?

In the sentence
“David jogs for a mile every day”
Jogs is the verb?

In the sentence
“David had jogged yesterday”
Had and jogged are both verbs

Comment: I'd say that "jogging" is also a verb in your first example. "I went jogging in the park yesterday".

Comment: *I went jogging* is no different in construction than *I like swimming*. In the latter, *swimming* is normally considered to be a gerund; as such, so should be *jogging*. (Whether or not you believe it's functioning as a verb or an noun, or what terminology you apply to it, is something different.)

Comment: There is a difference, @Jason.  In standard English, "I like that store" works, but "I went that store" doesn't.  The verb *to go* doesn't take a direct object.  The role of "jogging" in the first sentence is more like the role of a complete prepositional phrase, parallel to "I went *to* that store" or "I went *by* such a method" or "I went *for* that purpose."  If we're making a distinction between participle and gerund, this "jogging" doesn't fill a gerund-like role.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples, rearranged to put the two easier ones first:

**2** "David jogs for a mile every day”
Yes, "jogs" is the verb.

**3** “David had jogged yesterday”
"had jogged" is the verb "jog", conjugated as past perfect.
The verb "had" is an auxiliary, and it doesn't have a separate meaning; it just marks the past perfect.

**1** “I went jogging”
You can consider "went jogging" a verb.

The following text calls this usage one example, among others, of "verb + participle":
Oxford Guide to English Grammar, John Eastman
[Oxford "go/come + participle"](https://books.google.com/books?id=NrpZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22active%20participle%20to%20talk%20about%20some%20activities%20away%20from%20the%20home%22&dq=%22active%20participle%20to%20talk%20about%20some%20activities%20away%20from%20the%20home%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2ytjhhYrrAhWBQs0KHfnbD28Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg)

138 Verb + participle
(2)  **We use go/come + active participle to talk about some activities away from the home, especially leisure activities.**
*I'd love to go swimming.

We went riding yesterday.

Come cycling with us.

Mac goes jogging every morning.*
(The entire quotation is not available online).

This text calls it "verb + -ing":
[Collins Cobuild "v -ing"](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/grammar-pattern/v-ing_6)
I.4 The 'go riding' group
**These verbs are concerned with taking part in an activity, often shopping or a leisure activity.**
*The next afternoon Amy went riding with Gerald.*

It may be worth pointing out that "verb + participle" or "verb + ing" forms may vary significantly. Compare these sentences:
`I went running.` 
The main meaning is in "running", and "went" just means that I left home to do it.
`I came running.`
In that sentence, the main meaning is in "came", and "running" is more of an adverb. (For example, "When she called, I came running.")

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I went jogging*.
>
> [2] *David jogs for a mile every day*.
>
> [3] *David had jogged yesterday*.

In [1] "jogging" is undoubtedly a verb. The verb "go" is called a catenative verb because it takes non-finite gerund-participial clauses as complement. Here "went" has the clause "jogging" as complement. We know that "jogging" can't be a noun (your gerund) since "go" is intransitive, i.e. it's not possible to replace "jogging" with a 'real' noun (we can't say *I went shops" or *"I went Paris") etc.

In [2] "jogs" is clearly a verb, and in [3] "had jogged" is a perfect construction with the auxiliary verb "had" and the past participle verb "jogged".